# ColdFusion 8 Reading large Excel files

Tags: java, excel, coldfusion, apache-poi, large-files

I have been able to create my application so it can take Excel files with multiple sheets and put them into the database. However I'm not sure how I do this with large files 30mb+ I tried looking into `bufferedReader` but I'm not sure this is what I want since it reads a portion at a time and I am using Apache POI to read in multiple Excel sheets.

Currently if I send in a file to big I'm getting Java heap space errors, which is why I'm feeling the file is to large. During testing it worked fine, and then I used the 32mb file, and it failed.

Below is the code, I appreciate any help in advance. 
also myfile is an argument

```
ci_model = createObject("component", "com.data_feeds.models.ci.model_item_setup");
FileIn = createObject("java","java.io.FileInputStream").init(javacast("string", myfile));
wb = createObject("java","org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook").init(FileIn);
workbook = createObject("java","org.apache.poi.xssf.streaming.SXSSFWorkbook").init(wb);
sheetCount = workbook.getNumberOfSheets();

for(sheetIndex = 0; sheetIndex LT sheetCount; sheetIndex = sheetIndex + 1)
{
    recordIndex = 1;
    sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(sheetIndex);

    rowHeader = sheet.getFirstRowNum();
    rowCount = sheet.getLastRowNum();

    for (rowIndex = 1; rowIndex LTE rowCount; rowIndex = rowIndex + 1)
    {
        row = sheet.getRow(rowIndex);
        columnCount = row.getLastCellNum();

        for(columnIndex = 0; columnIndex LT columnCount; columnIndex = columnIndex +1)
        {
            record[recordIndex][columnIndex+1] = row.getCell(columnIndex);
            if((columnIndex+1)==4)
            {
                record[recordIndex][columnIndex+1] = ci_model.boolean_number(row.getCell(columnIndex).toString());
            }
        }
        recordIndex = recordIndex + 1;
        if(recordIndex == 500)
        {
            this.insert_record(record);
            arrayClear(record);
            request.help.debug.collect_garbage();
            recordIndex = 1;
        }
    }
    this.insert_record(record);
    arrayClear(record);
}
FileIn.close();
```

I am using ColdFusion 8.

Comment: You might have to do something to restrict the size of the file you accept.

Comment: Couple things. First, SXSSFWorkbook is for writing, not reading. Second, though you could obviously increase memory, ColdFusion really is not the best tool for large imports. You should look into importing with your database tools. What database/version are you using? (RE: `collect_garbage()` As an aside, you cannot *force* garbage collection, only suggest it. Ultimately the jvm determines *if* and when garbage collection will occur.)

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet is to import the data in a temporary table. Then import the data from the temporary table to the primary table using ColdFusion. This way you could use ColdFusion to simply import the data in chunks and not all at once.. To import into SQL Server all you need to do is use the import tool and for mySQL there are several ways you can. I personally just import using a csv file. I know this process is a bit less direct but it will put less strain on your  ColdFusion process and more on your SQL server.

Another suggestion is to also make sure your queries are not timing out or your page. Adding `?requestTimeout=1000` after your URL could also stop your process from timing out. I understand that it's a java error but if your process is lasting too long it could be timing out.

Comment: Yeah, the best thing to do is move the processing to the database which is better designed to handle this than CF. I do not think you mentioned your DBMS, but SQL Server has several options such as [SSIS, linked servers, openrowset, etcetera](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/321686). Temporary, or work tables, can be used be used as an extra layer to validate the data before completing the import into your main table.

Comment: Since we're offering alternative approaches, you could also consider converting the file to csv and then importing that. https://github.com/uniVocity/univocity-parsers makes it easy read the file line by line, so memory won't be an issue.